# Multiple dependent variables in equations, cycling through in for loops MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, dependencies

Alright so I'm trying to use MATLAB to find the set of variables: ed, ec, ef, efn, et, en so that my difference between Theoretical Thrust and Actual Thrust is less than .001. My code is never exiting my while statement even when the requirment is met. Any ideas?

```
    clear; clc;

B=5; Prf=1.5; M=.85; QR=43400000; Prc=30; Ta=288.2; Pa=101300; T04=1700; R=287; %ed=.97; ec=.85; et=.9; en=.98; 

% Turbojet Efficiencies and gammas 
gd=1.4; gc=1.33; gb=1.35; gt=1.33; gn=1.36; ActSpecificThrust = 800; ThSpecificThrust = 1020; g=1.4; gf=1.4; 

% Bypass Efficiencies (g/((g-1)*R)) T02 = Ta*(1+((g-1)/2)*M^2); 

while abs(ThSpecificThrust - ActSpecificThrust) >= .001
    for ed = 0.8: .05: .95
        for ec =.8:.05:.95
            for ef=.8:.05:.95
                for efn=.8:.05:.95
                    for et=.8:.05:.95
                        for en=.8:.05:.95

P02 = Pa*(1+ed*(T02/Ta-1))^(gd/(gd-1)); 
P03 = P02*Prc; T03 = T02*(1+(1/ec)*(Prc^((gc-1)/gc)-1)); 
f = (T04-T03)/((QR/1107)-T04); P04 = P03; P08 = P02*Prf; T08 = T02*(1+(1/ef)*(Prf^((gf-1)/gf)-1));
uef = (2*efn*(gf/(gf-1))*R*T08*(1-(Pa/P08)^((gf-1)/gf)))^(1/2); 
T05 = T04-(T03-T02)-B*(T08-T02); 
P05 = P04*(1-(1/et)*(1-(T05/T04)))^(gt/(gt-1)); 
T06 = T05; P06 = P05; P7=Pa; 
ue = (2*en*(gn/(gn-1))*R*T06*(1-(P7/P06)^((gn-1)/gn)))^(1/2);
u = M*(g*R*Ta)^(1/2);
ThSpecificThrust = (1+f)*ue+B*(uef)-(1+B)*u;
%TSFC = f/ASpecificThrust;
%ep = (SpecificThrust*u)/((1+f)*ue^2/2+B*uef^2/2-(1+B)*u^2/2); 
%eth = ((1+f)*ue^2/2+B*uef^2/2-(1+B)*u^2/2)/(f*QR); 
%e0 = ep*eth;

                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test your condition outside all of the for loops. Thus, MATLAB will test the condition, run through all combination of variables, test the condition again, etc.

What you probably want to do is test the condition inside the inner loop, and exit all loops if the condition is met. Given you have a script, not a function, the easiest way to exit all loops is to set a Boolean:

```
done=false;
for ...
  for ...
    % compute
    if condition
      done=true;
      break % exits inner for loop
    end
  end
  if done
    break % exits outer loop
  end
end
```

Since you have 6 loops, you'll need 6 break statements.

Better would be to write a function that contains your loops, and do a `return` in the inner loop when your condition is met.

Even better would be to use `fminsearch` or the like.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked that the requirement is met?

The vectors you are creating for each for loop have only five values (0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95), maybe the combinations of those values can't give you the expected value.

Checking the code again I've found that the value of ThSpThrust you are using for the while condition is calculated using the last value of each for loop (0.95). Basically you are checking abs(ThSpThrust(0.95, 0.95...) - AcSpThrust) >= 0.001

You should use a flag and a break statement once you find the right values. But you will need a break for each loop.

I would use fminsearch to minimize function = abs(ThSpThrust - AcSpThrust).

Comment: That's what I was thinking but when checking that the requirement is met and making the loop > 10 even it was met in the loop but never exiting.

Comment: Edited original answer.

Comment: When testing (ThSpecificThrust - ActSpecificThrust) inside the inner most for loop it is still cycling through each iteration of all of the for loops, like i want it to. The problem is that when it meets the requirement it does not break the loop. I can print out in the function that  difference and see the answer I want in one of  infinite iterations of answers.